# How to clear cookies of WinRT webview?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

Anyone knows how can I clear cookies of WinRT `WebView` ? If there's no in-build method, can any one have solution in JavaScript, so I can run that via `InvokeScript` method of `WebView`. Android and iOS is having simple 1-5 line of coding for clearing cookies, why not in WinRT ?

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 8 do this:

```
Array<String^>^ arguments = ref new Array<String^>(1);
arguments->set(0, "var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');" +
    "for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {" +
    "    var cookie = cookies[i];" +
    "    var eqPos = cookie.indexOf('=');" +
    "    var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;" +
    "    document.cookie = name + '=1;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT';" +
    "};");
String^ result = myWebView->InvokeScript("eval", arguments);
```

In Windows 8.1 Preview you may use [HttpCookieManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpcookiemanager.aspx) class.

Comment: @Xyroid JavaScript cannot touch HttpOnly cookies and the cookie from adidas.ca are HttpOnly, i.e.: Set-Cookie: dwsid=EM8HN23NpFToI_2pEeTJ0kL8Oz1XYkq-VqKPG8tH7AYmsuPe96bcqSLxsx9oqPhmFA-8ZKfRP8YH3FiFEPPzMw==; path=/; HttpOnly

Comment: So any solution for that ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can delete everything in Javascript, but I'll answer the other part of your question about being able to do it in WinRT. For your standard cookies, you can do:

```
    public void clearCookiesForUri(String uri)
    {
        Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter baseFilter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        HttpCookieCollection cookieCollection = baseFilter.CookieManager.GetCookies(new Uri(uri));

        Debug.WriteLine("Deleting cookies for " + uri);
        foreach (HttpCookie cookie in cookieCollection)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(cookie.Name + ": " + cookie.Value);
            baseFilter.CookieManager.DeleteCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
```

And the only way I've found to delete HttpOnly cookies is to clear all of the WebView's data via `WebView.ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync()`. It's pretty indiscriminate, but it works.